# Top-n-Box (Likert Scale) by factor groups in a dataframe

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, sum

I have the following dataframe, which is the result of a cluster analysis with ten 7-likert attitude scales for specific product benefits (see 'variable' column). At this, n is the number of persons stating a specific value for each Benefit and sum is the total sum of persons for each cluster. n2 is just the relative share of answers to all answers per cluster (n2=n/cum*100, which is basically %).

Now, I want to create a new column, aggregating / summing up **the top-n** (indicated in 'value' column) **percent** (indicated in n2) for **each** **benefit**, e.g. a new column "Top-3-Box" with e.g. a value of 46.5 for rows 1-7/Benefit.1 (which is the sum of the n2 of the rows with the top-3 value 7,6,5). It would be great if there would be a solution for this, which is instantly applicable in dplyr.

Please see the dataframe below:

```
     cluster variable   value     n   cum    n2
     <int> <chr>      <dbl> <int> <int> <dbl>
 1       1 Benefit.1      1    11    86  12.8
 2       1 Benefit.1      2    11    86  12.8
 3       1 Benefit.1      3     6    86   7  
 4       1 Benefit.1      4    18    86  20.9
 5       1 Benefit.1      5    16    86  18.6
 6       1 Benefit.1      6    14    86  16.3
 7       1 Benefit.1      7    10    86  11.6
 8       1 Benefit.10     1    10    86  11.6
 9       1 Benefit.10     2    13    86  15.1
10       1 Benefit.10     3     8    86   9.3
# ... with 40 more rows
```

I highly appreciate your support!

Comment: Just do `df1 %>% group_by(cluster, variable) %>% mutate(percent = sum(n2[value %in% 1:3]))`

Comment: @akrun Wow, so simple. Thank you very much for that quick support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do a group by `sum` of 'n2' by subsetting the values corresponding to the first 3 'value'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(cluster, variable) %>% 
    mutate(percent = sum(n2[value %in% 1:3]))
```

---

If the 'value' is already `order`ed per 'cluster', 'variable', then we can just subset the 'n2'

```
df1 %>% 
    group_by(cluster, variable) %>% 
    mutate(percent = sum(n2[1:3]))
```